# Toggle triangles on drop down answers

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, toggleclass

I am a newbie to Javascript, I have code I found on the internet for a drop-down FAQ file which works OK. What I cannot work out is how to adapt it to show toggle triangles - point right normally, point down when the answer drops down (as in here http://www.facebook.com/help/182071178590498/).

The main code is this:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#faq').find('dd').hide().end().find('dt').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
    </script>
    <style type="text/css"> 
#faq {
    width: 100%;
}
#faq dt {
    color: #2763A5;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 8px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#faq dd {
    border: 1px solid #BABAC0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFE1;
}
#faq dd p {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
    </style>
```

The FAQs and answers work with one dl line  + this repeating element:

```
    <dl id="faq">
<dt>
What are the benefits of solar energy?
</dt>
<dd><p>
When you <a href="installations.htm">install Solar water heating</a> in your home, you will reduce your impact on the environment. The system will pay for itself whilst reducing your fuel bills.
</p></dd>
```

The whole page can be seen here

http://contemporaryenergy.co.uk/faqs.htm

Any suggestions will be gratefully received. Patrick

Comment: Please consider posting a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), rather than expecting us to wade through the files of your site and work in the JavaScript console; help us to help you, make it *easy* for us to help you.

Comment: Point taken. I'm not only new to Javascript but this is my first attempt to get help on this forum and have yet to fully grasp the relevant forum etiquette, as it were.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at your code but typically you solve this by setting an extra CSS-class. Your default class could be:

```
.item {
    background-image: url("triangle.png");
}
```

Then you add/remove a class that replaces, or offsets the background image (if you're using a sprite)

```
.item.open {
    background-image: url("triangle-open.png");
    // or
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}
```